# Firestore denying permission to create/push collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am new to firebase / firestore and am trying to create a new collection upon login and authenticating a user, on client side and using React.
I read a few other articles here and I set the db rules to true for both read and write, but yet, I keep getting an error on the Firestore db, while it works perfectly if I initialise a Realtime Database.
Also, I can get and read data, but not write it.

The code I have is pretty simple:

```
    export default function Login() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticate] = useState(false);
  const [newEditor, setNewEditor] = useState("");
  const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (user) => {
        console.log("success");
        createUserRoles(newEditor);
      },
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        if (user.email.split("@")[1] === "something.com") {
          setAuthenticate(!!user);
          setNewEditor(user.email);
          console.log(newEditor);
        } else {
          console.log("not allowed");
        }
      }
    });
  });

  const createUserRoles = (user) => {
    //on login the user will be added to editors collection with default value of reviewer
    console.log("hello from createeee");
    const editorsRef = firebase.database().ref("editors");
    const editor = {
      email: "user.email",
      role: "reviewer",
      lastSession: Date.now(),
    };
    editorsRef.push(editor);
  };

  return (
.....
```

and my rules are set as such:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, double check that you're including the Firestore SDK in your code. Then...you're using RTDB syntax to try to add a document to Firestore in `createUserRoles`. You need to switch it to Firestore's syntax:

```js
const createUserRoles = async (user) => {
    //on login the user will be added to editors collection with default value of reviewer
    console.log("hello from createeee");
    // This is RTDB syntax for a ref
    // const editorsRef = firebase.database().ref("editors");
    // Try this instead
    const editorsRef = firebase.firestore().collection("editors");

    const editor = {
      email: "user.email",
      role: "reviewer",
      lastSession: Date.now(),
    };

    // This is how you add an item to RTDB
    // editorsRef.push(editor);
    // This is the Firestore way to create a new record with a random, unique document id
    await editorsRef.add(editor);
  };
```

Not also that reads and writes with Firestore (just like RTDB) are asynchronous so you need to use `async/await` (like I added) or `then/catch` promises.

Comment: Thank you Joe, this worked a treat! Much appreciated!